# REST API with websocket using Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, websocket

I am actually working to my university junior project.
I want to make a game using spring boot, this game will need a [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).
I will surely need to make a [REST API](https://restfulapi.net) for user registration, deleting, updating, posting and getting data.

Am I going to be able to use WebSocket along with REST?
If yes please send me resources that can help me, otherwise please tell me what should I do.
I'm sorry if my question was not so smart but I am new to all of this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, your Spring application can easily use both WebSocket and REST APIs. If you're going to use Spring Boot, I'd suggest to take a look into their [example projects](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples) (note the `spring-boot-sample-websocket-` directories). I think it's the best way to learn.

More on WebSockets, I'd suggest to use [STOMP](https://stomp.github.io/) protocol. There is also a [nice guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) for it on how you can get started.

For your RESTful API, you'll be making simple controllers / services, there is tones of resources for this. You can also follow [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) to get started as well.

Answer (score 1):

While Spring applications support both Websocket and REST API's individually, you can use Websocket connection to send requests to your rest API's too. Needs a little glitching tho, but I've made it work in this [github repo](https://github.com/idioglossia/spring-rest-over-ws). Using this library you can represent your rest-api's in a websocket based protocol.

I also made java (and springboot starter) for client.